# Are there ways to go to the selected channel using a button in the bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

In telegram there is a **KeyboardButtonRequestChat** object, when you click on the button it opens a list of chats sorted by certain criteria, then you can get the **id** of this chat using **ChatShared**. However, I would like to know if it is possible to make it so that when selecting a channel, the user goes to that channel, rather than sending it to the bot?

I would be grateful for any help.

```
@dp.message(Command('add_channel'))
async def add_channel(message: Message):
    await message.answer("I'm here", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
        [
            KeyboardButton(text="Channels", request_chat=KeyboardButtonRequestChat(
                request_id=1,
                user_is_bot=False,
                chat_is_channel=True,
                chat_is_forum=False
            )),
        ]
    ]
    ))
```

Comment: Can you see this question:

[share-profile-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76346417/how-to-implement-a-share-profile-button-in-aiogram-like-premiumbot)